# When editing XML in eclipse, can I change stopping behavior of caret?

Tags: eclipse, editor

When editing Java code in Eclipse, assume you have the following word with | being the caret.

```
ThisIsACamel|CaseWord
```

If I press ctrl-right, the caret moves to the next capital giving me

```
ThisIsACamelCase|Word
```

so far, so good. Eclipse calls this *smart caret positioning*.

Now when editing XML (GWT / GXT files in this case), I also often have camel case words. But in this editor, camel case is not taken into account and the caret would jump directly to the end of the word.

Is there a way to fix this behavior so that smart caret positioning works in the XML editor too ?

Comment: You might look at opening the XML file in the plain text editor and seeing if that changes the behavior. You can permanently set the editor preference in the preferences dialog in the File Types section, I think it is.

Comment: Opening the file with the plain text editor does nothing. Opening it with the java editor enables smart caret positioning, but messes up the formatting and content assist, so not an acceptable workaround.